# Xcode does not see the segue

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode

In my app I need to after the application has been minimized, and then open the application screen switched to a certain ViewController, it introduces the password if it is correct, the view switches to the main screen.

My AppDelegate.m:

```
-(void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
    EnterBackground *vc = [[EnterBackground alloc] init];
    self.window.rootViewController = vc;
}
```

In the Storyboard, it looks like this:

[image]

And EnterBackground.m:

```
if ([checkCode isEqualToString:@"111"])
    [self perfomSegueWithIdentifier:@"ss" sender: self];
```

But when I enter the password, and must go, an error that no segue with identifier 'ss'. Although it exists. I have a similar connection ( in green circle) with another ViewController, and modal segue works. 
I tried also: `[self navigationController performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ss" sender:self];` With this I don't see an error, but I can see only black screen.
What could be wrong?

Comment: - Have you tried cleaning your product in Xcode?
- Have you renamed your Storyboard file?
- Have you tried cleaning your DerivedData folder (or simply removed the app from simulator)?

Comment: Did you check you did not use the (somewhat unsettling) identifier "ss" somewhere else?

Comment: @Martijn I reset simulator defaults - no changed

Comment: @Mundi, yes, I'm sure

Comment: Resetting sim defaults won't do it. Can you answer all 3 questions

Comment: @Martijn, I have cleaned product, I didn't renamed my Storyboard

Comment: Thank you all. The problem was that I was an idiot). I put in the perfomSegue... @"ss'" (not just @"ss"). But it before didn't work, gameCon and Ashwani are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the applicationDidEnterBackground method try something like:

```
UIStoryboard *storybord = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
EnterBackground *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"EnterBackgroundVC"];
self.window.rootViewController = vc;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should get your 'EnterBackground' instance from the storyboard, not by initializing it manually. The info about segues of 'EnterBackground' comes from storyboard not from the class implementation. This is how you can initialize it properly:

```
 UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"YourStoryboardFilename" bundle:nil];
 EnterBackground *vcEnterBackground = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"StoryboardIdentifierOfEnterBackground"];
```